# Approach for developing client side web libraries (e.g. webjars)

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, webjars

I have a number of internal projects that are essentially client-side web assets that I'd like to distribute to colleagues as [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/) via our repository manager.  So far the development process has been:

1. Build an example webapp that includes the web assets I'd like to distribute and test.
2. Create a separate project with copies of the assets located in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` rather than `src/main/webapp`; set `<packaging>` to jar rather than war in pom.xml. Build and deploy the jar artifact to the repository manager.
3. Create a third project as a testbed to verify that everything works correctly when the jar file from (2) is included as a project dependency.

I'd like to combine (1) and (2) so that I can test and release from a single project. I'll need to get Maven to selectively move the distributable assets to the right locations. Seems like I'd also need a way to switch `<packaging>` as well. Any suggestions on how to do this or better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a good way to deal with this when using WAR-based webapps because WAR files aren't like JAR files.  If you were using a non-WAR-based web framework (Play Framework, Dropwizard, etc) then you could definitely keep JAR packaging and have both the static assets and the testing app in a single JAR.

Comment: Your answer makes me think of [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) - maybe I could build an executable jar with embedded Tomcat for testing and a stripped down jar for release?